# useRef is working in async but not outside - React native

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I have this code but when I log processedData in onViewableItemsChanged it log nothing but when I log it in requestDb it works.
I have tu use processedData in a component  so I need it outside async function
Here is my code :

```js
    const [processedData, setProcessedData] = useState([]);
    const getUserById = async (uuid: string) => {
        const docRef = doc(FIREBASE_DB, "profiles", uuid);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

        if (docSnap.exists()) {
            return docSnap.data();
        }
    }

    const requestDb = async (data: any) => {
        let user = await getUserById(data[0].user_id);

        const processedData = data.map((item: any) => ({
            id: item.id,
            user: {
                name: user?.username,
                profile: user?.avatar_url,
            },
        }));
        setProcessedData(processedData);
        return processedData; // Retourner les données traitées
    }


    const onViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({ viewableItems }: any) => {
        if (viewableItems.length > 0) {
            requestDb(viewableItems.map((item: any) => item.item));
            console.log(processedData)
        }
    }).current;
```